# Should a HTTP 404 precede a HTTP 403 status code?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have created a web service (RESTful) with Spring MVC 3.1 and I have added Spring security. One of the endpoints is `/users/{id}` which should only be available to administrators. However `/users/{id}` is also available to a user if and only if the username of the retrieved resource matches that of the logged in user. This is solved by using a @PostAuthorize annotation.

Now, if a user access `/users/999` (which is not the logged in user), should I return HTTP status 404 or HTTP status 403? Currently I am doing a 404 (not found), but should it have been a 403 since the user shouldn't be able to access it?

If so, how would you do that when you rely on a @PostAutorize annotation?

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.username == principal.username and hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use 404, because whether the resource exists or not is not information a non-administrative user should have. This is even covered in [the HTTP specification with regard to code 403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.4):

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
> public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
> reason for the refusal in the entity.  **If the server does not wish to
> make this information available to the client, the status code 404
> (Not Found) can be used instead.**

*(My emphasis.)*

If you used 403 instead, you'd have to use 403 when replying to non-admin requests for resources that didn't exist, otherwise your implementation would be leaking information (which users exist and don't) to non-admin users who shouldn't have that information.

There's an argument for using 403 (even if the user doesn't exist), but I think 404 edges it out. However, whichever you use, use it *consistently* when replying to requests from non-admin users for user pages other than their own, to avoid the information leak.

Comment: As a pentester, I would flag this as Information Disclosure since I would be able to enumerate accounts. In general, as a developer, I would never return an HTTP status code of 403 for anything, including resource paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 403 as the resource is available but user is not allowed. HTTP 403 specification clearly mentions that:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.
>
> A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response
>   to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that
>   the server refuses to allow the requested action. In other words, the
>   server can be reached, but the server declined to allow the requested
>   access.

Comment: So, how would you do that with Spring Security with the config that I mentioned?

Comment: And btw: in this case 999 is not a resource, not even for administrators. It does't exists. If the resource exists it returns 403. But the case is where it doesn't exists.

Comment: @LuckyLuke: Beware information leak! If the user can't see `/users/999` (which doesn't exist) and `/users/998` (which does), you don't want to reply with a 404 to the `/users/999` but a 403 to the `/users/998`. That leaks information the user almost certainly shouldn't have access to. Either always use 404, or always use 403 (you could use 404 with administrators when they ask for a user that doesn't exist, since that is information they are allowed to know).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If your application is secured it does not matter about the information leak. If you simply return 404, then debugging an authorization problem will be different. Because you will be not be sure whether 404 is because the resource is not available or user is not allowed to access it.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: *"If your application is secured it does not matter about the information leak."* I strongly disagree. :-) Security is an onion. Don't peel away layers when you don't have to.